# Getting Nested response model in fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

When accessing localhost:8000/#doc, the nested response model is not displayed correctly. However, after merging and deploying my local changes to the server, the documentation appears as expected.

```
T = TypeVar('T')
class StandardSuccessResponse(BaseModel, Generic[T]):
    url: str
    duration: int
    response: T

class AddClipPhraseResponse(BaseModel):
    clip_vector: str

@router.post("/clip/phrases",
             description="Adds a phrase to the clip server.",
             tags=["clip"],
             response_model=StandardSuccessResponse[AddClipPhraseResponse],
             status_code=201,
             responses=ApiResponseHandler.listErrors([400, 422, 500, 503]))
```

Now response model on local like this:

```
{
  "url": "string",
  "duration": 0,
  "response": "string"
}


but on the deployment server it look like this:

{
  "url": "string",
  "duration": 0,
  "response": {
    "clip_vector": "string"
  }
}
```

why it does not return same response model for my locally?

Comment: How did you run your app locally ?

Comment: just with uvicorn. like run main.py

Comment: did you use `--reload` ?

Comment: Although your query is well-posed and precise, it might use some additional details to aid in a more accurate diagnosis of the problem. 
Because they may have an impact on the behavior you're seeing, mention the frameworks or libraries you're using.
Indicate the versions of these libraries on the server as well as on your local setup, as version discrepancies can occasionally lead to inconsistent results.
Look for any customizations unique to the environment that might be affecting the format of the response model.
If you have access to logs or e

Comment: to continue... -"or errors"